# Format price decimal points

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, price, format

I've displayed item's price (both old price and new price) using this code,

```
<?php echo $_item->getProduct()->getPrice(); ?>
```

But when I see the page, it displays price with 4 decimal numbers,
like 150.0000

I need to change number of decimals after the `.` to be two. like 15.00

How can I do this?
I'm okay with however getting formatted number, when `$_item->getProduct()->getPrice();` gives 15.0000 I need to change it into 15.00 however way possible.

Can anybody help me?

**- NOTE -**

I've found `php` way to format the numbers.

```
<?php $oldprice = $_item->getProduct()->getPrice();
             echo number_format($oldprice, 2, ".", ","); 
             ?>
```

*But the problem is, I've to put this everywhere I need to change the format*

Answer (score 8):

You can format the Price using the below Code:

```
public function __construct(
    /* Add below dependencies */
    \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $pricingHelper,
) {
    $this->pricingHelper = $pricingHelper;
}

/*Call the below function to format amount*/
$this->pricingHelper->currency($amount,true,false);
```

**In template file, you can use the below code:**

```
$pricHelper = $this->helper('\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data');
echo $pricHelper->currency($amount,true,false);
```

Comment: Hi, where should I put this?

Comment: I have updated the answer, in template you can use like that way

Comment: sorry, im not an expert. where should I put the construct?

Answer (score 6):

You can use this format

**Using Object manager :**

```
$price=$objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency(number_format($value->getPrice(),2));
```

**Using Construct :**

```
public function __construct(
    /* Add below dependencies */
    \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $pricingHelper,
) {
    $this->pricingHelper = $pricingHelper;
}

/*Call the below function to format amount*/
$this->pricingHelper->currency($price,true,false);
```

**Note :** *Do not use object manager directly.*

Comment: to where should I need to put this? I need to apply this filter throughout my theme. to whole site. To every place that display price

Comment: Where you display price, You can set this code instead of your code.

Comment: If it is useful and right answer , Please approve this answer. So, This code is useful to other people. :)

Comment: I need to set this filter to my whole site, without editing core files, but only inside theme folder. can I do that? if yes, how?

Comment: I agian told you that from where you display your product price at that place you can set this code instead of your code. If you display your product price from theme then put there. Otherwise, you need to change in all files from where you display.

Comment: I asked do I need to put this every place I need to format the price or can I use this at one place that'll affect the whole site. From replies you've given it seems I may need to put this code in each and every location I need to format price. Thank you @Rohan Hapani

Answer (score 2):

For change Currency formate please change in below files

**vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/PriceCurrencyInterface.php**

> const DEFAULT_PRECISION = 2;

**vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/Currency.php**

> return $this->formatPrecision($price, 2, $options, $includeContainer,
>   $addBrackets);

**vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order.php**

> public function formatPrice($price, $addBrackets = false) {
>       return $this->formatPricePrecision($price, 2, $addBrackets); }

Comment: Appreciate the help. Isn't it bad practice to modify core files? either way, I need to acomplish the task without editing core files. I can edit items inside my theme so that's what I'm looking for. Can you help me with that?

Comment: You can use plugin to do this. Plugin is the best way to change the core behaviour.