# Change product price precision to 3

Tags: magento2, pricing

I need to change the product price precision to 3. Is this configurable in the magento admin panel or how can I achive this with custom code_

Thank you for your help !

I tryed this solution but when I add the product to the cart it rounds the value to decimal points.

[Magento 2.1 pricing in 4 decimal places](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275512/magento-2-1-pricing-in-4-decimal-places)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a lot of banging my head against the wall I managed to solve the problem this way.
I read the product prices from a web-service, in your case if you read them from Magento you will need to find way to input this prices with 3 precision digits !

This code will allow make magento use 3 precision digits for price. To calculate the subtotal of a row it will make price (3precision digits) * qty and round the value to two precision digits. All totals/subtotals will be two digits.

**/app/code/vendor/module/etc/di.xml**

```
<preference for="Magento\Directory\Model\PriceCurrency"                     type="vendor\module\Model\Directory\PriceCurrency"/>
    <preference for="Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\TotalBaseCalculator"         type="vendor\module\Preferences\Calculation\TotalBaseCalculator"/>
    <preference for="Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\RowBaseCalculator"           type="vendor\module\Preferences\Calculation\RowBaseCalculator"/>
```

**/vendor/module/Model/Directory/PriceCurrency.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace vendor\module\Model\Directory;

use Magento\Framework\App\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory;

/**
 * Class PriceCurrency model for convert and format price value
 */
class PriceCurrency extends \Magento\Directory\Model\PriceCurrency
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var CurrencyFactory
     */
    protected $currencyFactory;

    /**
     * @var Logger
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory
     * @param Logger $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory,
        Logger $logger
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->currencyFactory = $currencyFactory;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function convert($amount, $scope = null, $currency = null)
    {
        $currentCurrency = $this->getCurrency($scope, $currency);

        return $this->getStore($scope)
            ->getBaseCurrency()
            ->convert($amount, $currentCurrency);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function convertAndRound($amount, $scope = null, $currency = null, $precision = self::DEFAULT_PRECISION)
    {
        return $this->roundPrice($this->convert($amount, $scope, $currency), 2);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function format(
        $amount,
        $includeContainer = true,
        $precision = self::DEFAULT_PRECISION,
        $scope = null,
        $currency = null
    ) {
        return $this->getCurrency($scope, $currency)
            ->formatPrecision($amount, 2, [], $includeContainer);
    }


     /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function formatCartPrice(
        $amount,
        $includeContainer = true,
        $precision = self::DEFAULT_PRECISION,
        $scope = null,
        $currency = null
    ) {
        return $this->getCurrency($scope, $currency)
            ->formatPrecision($amount, 3, [], $includeContainer);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function convertAndFormat(
        $amount,
        $includeContainer = true,
        $precision = self::DEFAULT_PRECISION,
        $scope = null,
        $currency = null
    ) {
        $amount = $this->convert($amount, $scope, $currency);

        return $this->format($amount, $includeContainer, 2, $scope, $currency);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getCurrency($scope = null, $currency = null)
    {
        if ($currency instanceof Currency) {
            $currentCurrency = $currency;
        } elseif (is_string($currency)) {
            $currency = $this->currencyFactory->create()
                ->load($currency);
            $baseCurrency = $this->getStore($scope)
                ->getBaseCurrency();
            $currentCurrency = $baseCurrency->getRate($currency) ? $currency : $baseCurrency;
        } else {
            $currentCurrency = $this->getStore($scope)
                ->getCurrentCurrency();
        }

        return $currentCurrency;
    }

    /**
     * Get currrency symbol
     *
     * @param null|string|bool|int|\Magento\Framework\App\ScopeInterface $scope
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel|string|null $currency
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCurrencySymbol($scope = null, $currency = null)
    {
        return $this->getCurrency($scope, $currency)->getCurrencySymbol();
    }

    /**
     * Get store model
     *
     * @param null|string|bool|int|ScopeInterface $scope
     * @return Store
     */
    protected function getStore($scope = null)
    {
        try {
            if (!$scope instanceof Store) {
                $scope = $this->storeManager->getStore($scope);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
            $scope = $this->storeManager->getStore();
        }

        return $scope;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function round($price)
    {
        return round($price, 2);
    }

    /**
     * Round price with precision
     *
     * @param float $price
     * @param int $precision
     * @return float
     */
    public function roundPrice($price, $precision = self::DEFAULT_PRECISION)
    {
        return round($price, 2);
    }
}
```

**/vendor/module/Preferences/Calculation/RowBaseCalculator.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace vendor\module\Preferences\Calculation;

use Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterface;

class RowBaseCalculator extends \Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\RowBaseCalculator
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function roundAmount(
        $amount,
        $rate = null,
        $direction = null,
        $type = self::KEY_REGULAR_DELTA_ROUNDING,
        $round = true,
        $item = null
    ) {
        if ($item->getAssociatedItemCode()) {
            // Use delta rounding of the product's instead of the weee's
            $type = $type . $item->getAssociatedItemCode();
        } else {
            $type = $type . $item->getCode();
        }

        return $this->deltaRound($amount, $rate, $direction, $type, $round);
    }

    protected function calculateWithTaxNotInPrice(QuoteDetailsItemInterface $item, $quantity, $round = true)
    {
        $taxRateRequest = $this->getAddressRateRequest()->setProductClassId(
            $this->taxClassManagement->getTaxClassId($item->getTaxClassKey())
        );
        $rate = $this->calculationTool->getRate($taxRateRequest);
        $appliedRates = $this->calculationTool->getAppliedRates($taxRateRequest);

        $applyTaxAfterDiscount = $this->config->applyTaxAfterDiscount($this->storeId);
        $discountAmount = $item->getDiscountAmount();
        $discountTaxCompensationAmount = 0;

        // Calculate $rowTotal
        $price = $item->getUnitPrice();
        $rowTotal = $price * $quantity;
        $rowTaxes = [];
        $rowTaxesBeforeDiscount = [];
        $appliedTaxes = [];
        $rowTotalForTaxCalculation = $this->getPriceForTaxCalculation($item, $price) * $quantity;
        //Apply each tax rate separately
        foreach ($appliedRates as $appliedRate) {
            $taxId = $appliedRate['id'];
            $taxRate = $appliedRate['percent'];
            $rowTaxPerRate = $this->calculationTool->calcTaxAmount($rowTotalForTaxCalculation, $taxRate, false, false);
            $deltaRoundingType = self::KEY_REGULAR_DELTA_ROUNDING;
            if ($applyTaxAfterDiscount) {
                $deltaRoundingType = self::KEY_TAX_BEFORE_DISCOUNT_DELTA_ROUNDING;
            }
            $rowTaxPerRate = $this->roundAmount($rowTaxPerRate, $taxId, false, $deltaRoundingType, $round, $item);
            $rowTaxAfterDiscount = $rowTaxPerRate;

            //Handle discount
            if ($applyTaxAfterDiscount) {
                //TODO: handle originalDiscountAmount
                $taxableAmount = max($rowTotalForTaxCalculation - $discountAmount, 0);
                if ($taxableAmount && !$applyTaxAfterDiscount) {
                    $taxableAmount = $rowTotalForTaxCalculation;
                }
                $rowTaxAfterDiscount = $this->calculationTool->calcTaxAmount(
                    $taxableAmount,
                    $taxRate,
                    false,
                    false
                );
                $rowTaxAfterDiscount = $this->roundAmount(
                    $rowTaxAfterDiscount,
                    $taxId,
                    false,
                    self::KEY_REGULAR_DELTA_ROUNDING,
                    $round,
                    $item
                );
            }
            $appliedTaxes[$taxId] = $this->getAppliedTax(
                $rowTaxAfterDiscount,
                $appliedRate
            );

            $rowTaxes[] = $rowTaxAfterDiscount;
            $rowTaxesBeforeDiscount[] = $rowTaxPerRate;
        }
        $rowTax = array_sum($rowTaxes);
        $rowTaxBeforeDiscount = array_sum($rowTaxesBeforeDiscount);
        $rowTotalInclTax = $rowTotal + $rowTaxBeforeDiscount;
        $priceInclTax = $rowTotalInclTax / $quantity;

        if ($round) {
            $priceInclTax = $this->calculationTool->round($priceInclTax);
        }

        return $this->taxDetailsItemDataObjectFactory->create()
            ->setCode($item->getCode())
            ->setType($item->getType())
            ->setRowTax($rowTax)
            ->setPrice($price)
            ->setPriceInclTax($priceInclTax)
            ->setRowTotal($rowTotal)
            ->setRowTotalInclTax($rowTotalInclTax)
            ->setDiscountTaxCompensationAmount($discountTaxCompensationAmount)
            ->setAssociatedItemCode($item->getAssociatedItemCode())
            ->setTaxPercent($rate)
            ->setAppliedTaxes($appliedTaxes);
    }

    /**
     * Get price for tax calculation.
     *
     * @param QuoteDetailsItemInterface $item
     * @param float $price
     * @return float
     */
    private function getPriceForTaxCalculation(QuoteDetailsItemInterface $item, float $price)
    {
        if ($item->getExtensionAttributes() && $item->getExtensionAttributes()->getPriceForTaxCalculation()) {
            $priceForTaxCalculation = $item->getExtensionAttributes()->getPriceForTaxCalculation();
        } else {
            $priceForTaxCalculation = $price;
        }

        return $priceForTaxCalculation;
    }
}
```

**/vendor/module/Preferences/Calculation/TotalBaseCalculator.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace vendor\module\Preferences\Calculation;

use Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterface;

class TotalBaseCalculator extends  \Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\TotalBaseCalculator
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function roundAmount(
        $amount,
        $rate = null,
        $direction = null,
        $type = self::KEY_REGULAR_DELTA_ROUNDING,
        $round = true,
        $item = null
    ) {
        return $this->deltaRound($amount, $rate, $direction, $type, $round);
    }

    protected function calculateWithTaxNotInPrice(QuoteDetailsItemInterface $item, $quantity, $round = true)
    {
        $taxRateRequest = $this->getAddressRateRequest()->setProductClassId(
            $this->taxClassManagement->getTaxClassId($item->getTaxClassKey())
        );
        $rate = $this->calculationTool->getRate($taxRateRequest);
        $appliedRates = $this->calculationTool->getAppliedRates($taxRateRequest);

        $applyTaxAfterDiscount = $this->config->applyTaxAfterDiscount($this->storeId);
        $discountAmount = $item->getDiscountAmount();
        $discountTaxCompensationAmount = 0;

        // Calculate $rowTotal
        $price = $item->getUnitPrice();
        $rowTotal = $this->calculationTool->round($price * $quantity);
        $rowTaxes = [];
        $rowTaxesBeforeDiscount = [];
        $appliedTaxes = [];
        $rowTotalForTaxCalculation = $this->getPriceForTaxCalculation($item, $price) * $quantity;
        //Apply each tax rate separately
        foreach ($appliedRates as $appliedRate) {
            $taxId = $appliedRate['id'];
            $taxRate = $appliedRate['percent'];
            $rowTaxPerRate = $this->calculationTool->calcTaxAmount($rowTotalForTaxCalculation, $taxRate, false, false);
            $deltaRoundingType = self::KEY_REGULAR_DELTA_ROUNDING;
            if ($applyTaxAfterDiscount) {
                $deltaRoundingType = self::KEY_TAX_BEFORE_DISCOUNT_DELTA_ROUNDING;
            }
            $rowTaxPerRate = $this->roundAmount($rowTaxPerRate, $taxId, false, $deltaRoundingType, $round, $item);
            $rowTaxAfterDiscount = $rowTaxPerRate;

            //Handle discount
            if ($applyTaxAfterDiscount) {
                //TODO: handle originalDiscountAmount
                $taxableAmount = max($rowTotalForTaxCalculation - $discountAmount, 0);
                if ($taxableAmount && !$applyTaxAfterDiscount) {
                    $taxableAmount = $rowTotalForTaxCalculation;
                }
                $rowTaxAfterDiscount = $this->calculationTool->calcTaxAmount(
                    $taxableAmount,
                    $taxRate,
                    false,
                    false
                );
                $rowTaxAfterDiscount = $this->roundAmount(
                    $rowTaxAfterDiscount,
                    $taxId,
                    false,
                    self::KEY_REGULAR_DELTA_ROUNDING,
                    $round,
                    $item
                );
            }
            $appliedTaxes[$taxId] = $this->getAppliedTax(
                $rowTaxAfterDiscount,
                $appliedRate
            );

            $rowTaxes[] = $rowTaxAfterDiscount;
            $rowTaxesBeforeDiscount[] = $rowTaxPerRate;
        }
        $rowTax = array_sum($rowTaxes);
        $rowTaxBeforeDiscount = array_sum($rowTaxesBeforeDiscount);
        $rowTotalInclTax = $rowTotal + $rowTaxBeforeDiscount;
        $priceInclTax = $rowTotalInclTax / $quantity;

        if ($round) {
            $priceInclTax = $this->calculationTool->round($priceInclTax);
        }

        return $this->taxDetailsItemDataObjectFactory->create()
            ->setCode($item->getCode())
            ->setType($item->getType())
            ->setRowTax($rowTax)
            ->setPrice($price)
            ->setPriceInclTax($priceInclTax)
            ->setRowTotal($rowTotal)
            ->setRowTotalInclTax($rowTotalInclTax)
            ->setDiscountTaxCompensationAmount($discountTaxCompensationAmount)
            ->setAssociatedItemCode($item->getAssociatedItemCode())
            ->setTaxPercent($rate)
            ->setAppliedTaxes($appliedTaxes);
    }

    /**
     * Get price for tax calculation.
     *
     * @param QuoteDetailsItemInterface $item
     * @param float $price
     * @return float
     */
    private function getPriceForTaxCalculation(QuoteDetailsItemInterface $item, float $price)
    {
        if ($item->getExtensionAttributes() && $item->getExtensionAttributes()->getPriceForTaxCalculation()) {
            $priceForTaxCalculation = $item->getExtensionAttributes()->getPriceForTaxCalculation();
        } else {
            $priceForTaxCalculation = $price;
        }

        return $priceForTaxCalculation;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine on 2.4.3. But on 2.4.4, it doesn't seem to be referenced at all. I have checked and the module is installed. If you could please help with suggestions on where should I be looking to solve this?

Comment: @sanketpahuja did you get any solutions?

Comment: Hi Dhaval. Nope, we ended up not going for the upgrade and sticking with 2.4.3