# Custom Module Not Working in 2.4.4 but working in 2.4.3

Tags: price, magento2.4, tax-calculation

I have implemented a custom module based on this thread -https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/339930/change-product-price-precision-to-3

It's working perfectly fine on Magento 2.4.3, but no changes are reflecting when I upgrade to 2.4.4. But the module is installed successfully.

My module structure-

```
/app/code/Sanket/PricePrecision
 ->registration.php
 ->/etc
   ->module.xml
   ->di.xml
 ->/Model
   ->PriceCurrency.php
   ->RowBaseCalculator.php
   ->TotalBaseCalculator.php
```

My registration.php

```
<?php 

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 
    'Sanket_PricePrecision',
    __DIR__
);
```

My di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Directory\Model\PriceCurrency" type="Bedee\PricePrecision\Model\PriceCurrency"/>
    <preference for="Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\TotalBaseCalculator" type="Bedee\PricePrecision\Model\TotalBaseCalculator"/>
    <preference for="Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\RowBaseCalculator" type="Bedee\PricePrecision\Model\RowBaseCalculator"/>

</config>
```

My module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Sanket_PricePrecision" setup_version="1.2.2">
        <sequence>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: In your `di.xml` you have namespace `Bedee\PricePrecision`, but module namespace is `Sanket\PricePrecision`. You didn't specify what exactly doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

See the code below for Magento 2.4.4

registration.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(
    ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Sanket_PricePrecision',
    __DIR__
);
```

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Sanket_PricePrecision" setup_version="1.2.2">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```