# What to do in order to allow hyperinflationary currencies? (How to increase decimals limit)

Tags: magento2, database, price, multicurrency, database-schema

We have to allow in our multi-currency site currency that's very hyperinflationary. Base price for products are set in USD but We have some products shown in VEF that are very close to Magento 2 maximum limit of 99,999,999.99 and not even to mention the orders totals.

We tried to make some changes in the Database but We noticed this is not enough. It seems somewhere there's some limit in code and probably something turning tables back to 12,4 decimals once you reindex in Magento.

Can someone help?

Comment: Please follow below link, this may help you a bit.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200556/format-price-decimal-points/200565#200565

Comment: @mighty_hk that link is not really related on how to increase max number digits limit in Magento.

Comment: Not an answer... but you are going to have a very difficult time solving this requiring massive code changes and database modifications and ultimately may not be worth the effort. Would it be possible to require them to purchase in another currency and maybe write a little javascript tool that pops up with the currency conversion on a few pages (checkout, product)?